# not getting alexa rank for website

Tags: php

I'm trying to get alexa rank for any link. I have found one simple class which is

```
Class Alexa {

    function getAlexaRank($url)
    {
        $request_url = "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=".$url;
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("feed not loading");
        return $xml->SD->POPULARITY['TEXT'];
    }

}
```

when I go to this link

http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=google.com

I get

```
<SD>
<POPULARITY URL="google.com/" TEXT="2" SOURCE="panel"/>
<REACH RANK="1"/>
<RANK DELTA="+1"/>
<COUNTRY CODE="US" NAME="United States" RANK="1"/>
</SD>
```

but why this class doesn't work? it doesn't return anything

thank you :)

Comment: That is because the class is broken. Contact the author of the class and do a bug-report, we can not handle third-party code here but only your own code.

Comment: There are two SD nodes.. so you can try this `$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY['TEXT'];`

Comment: it works in my localhost only. but in my host doesn't. what do you think is the problem? should I contact my host?

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
/**
 * Get Popularity Text of a Domain via Alexa XML Data
 *
 * @return string|FALSE text or FALSE on error
 */
function alexa_get_rank($domain)
{
    $alexa = "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=%s";
    $request_url =  sprintf($alexa, urlencode($domain));

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
    if (!$xml) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $nodeAttributes = $xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes();
    $text = (string) $nodeAttributes['TEXT'];

    return $text;
}

var_dump(alexa_get_rank('google.com'));
// string(1) "2"
```

Comment: it works in my localhost only. but in my host doesn't. what do you think is the problem? should I contact my host?